# How to display custom message on Maven build failure

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

When I run a clean Maven profile build ("mvn clean install -PmyProfile"), I want the ability to present a custom, static text message to the user if the build fails.

For example, from this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:54.666s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 13 10:44:48 MDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

to this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:54.666s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 13 10:44:48 MDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] For troubleshooting steps for your build, go to http://www.somewhere.com
[INFO]
[INFO] If you continue to have trouble, email Some Guy at some_guy@somewhere.com
[INFO]
```

Is this possible in Maven?

Comment: You have to change the Maven sources.

Comment: I'm not clear on how changing the maven sources would allow a me message to present some static text if the unit tests fail.  Can you explain?

Comment: The output which you described in your post is comming from Maven itself. The question is why you need such thing? If the test fail you get an appropriate message.

Comment: We have a very large, complex, changing development environment where a failure may not be a true failure.  I am investigating ways we can message to developers and testers information about the build and where they can troubleshoot any breaks.  It makes sense to us to provide these options at the point of failure rather than some other means.  The above is a very simple example.

Comment: Does the development evironment change really cause a build failure? Than i think something is wrong. `mvn clean package` or `mvn install` should be run from a continious integration system or command line. Furthermore if you have several envrionments than it might be wise to build for those environments and deploy the results later on it. In case of integration tests you can create a reporting (maven site or continious integration like Jenkins) which shows which test case(s) have failed which indicates the cause of the failure.

Comment: I appreciate your opinions khmarbaise.  However we are getting off subject in this discussion.  The question I posted is about adding an additional tool to our collection for conveying information to the person who ran the build.  You mentioned before that I could 'change the Maven sources'.  Can you explain that further please?

Answer (score 0):

Use a component which handles the MojoFailureException:

```
@Component
private MojoExecution execution;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException 
  {
  for (Artifact artifact : (Collection<Artifact>) execution.getMojoDescriptor().getPluginDescriptor().getArtifacts()) 
    {
    getLog().info("Artifact: " + artifact);
    }
  }
```

**References**

- [MojoFailureException API](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoFailureException.html)
- [Maven HelpUtil Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugins/help/HelpUtil.html)
- [When a Mojo Fails](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html#writing-plugins-sect-failure)
- [Maven Quick Reference Card (pdf)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/MavenQuickReferenceCard.pdf)